# Search and replace without changing the highlighting?

Tags: vim

I use a key binding to add/remove comments in a given line.

Since I don't want Vim to highlight the beginning of all comments after I use it, the key binding includes

```
<CR>:nohlsearch<CR>
```

One problem with this, is that it kills all highlighting. What I'd really like to do, is revert to whatever was highlighted before.

Is this possible in Vim?

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: Have you thought about using a [commenting plugin](http://vimawesome.com/?q=comment), like [commentary.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary)? A well supported comment plugin can handle often handle more filetypes and way more robust than most homegrown solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
let old = @/      " preserve the old search
%s/foo/bar/g      " search for foo and replace with bar
let @/ = old      " stop highlighting "foo" and highlight whatever we did before
```